# Is it possible to retrieve and send data from google docs to android app?

Tags: android, google-api, google-docs

I understand how to receive and send data from an android app to a server database, be it involving a connection between PHP (server) and Android (client) using HTTP.

Is it possible to use Google Docs and Google API to accomplish the same task? As in sending information to and from an android app to a Google Doc and have the app use that data to update information without actually changing code and releasing an update for the app itself?

I realize there are several other questions already answered on a similar topic but I can't seem to find the specific answer I am looking for, so please help!

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, you are talking about sending/receiving data to/from Google Docs, but then you are asking if this can be done to replace having to update your app? Google Docs stores documents, that is all. It is not for "database" storage.

Comment: Ok I understand that I am kinda mixing up my words, and part of the reason stems from not completly understanding how google docs can be implemented in applications. So basically are you saying that google docs can not be used as a substitute for updating information on an app when compared to accomplishing the same task by using a web application connected to a server database?

Comment: Correct. Google docs essentially allows you to do two things: store docs and retrieve docs of type docx, xls, pdf, etc.... It does not store information as MySQL or some other DB would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with a cloud-based service in Android, you need a protocol that both the service and Android support, such as HTTP. Once you have that, you use the protocol to send requests to the service and retrieve the results. Sync adapters do this. The SampleSyncAdapter sample app, among others, shows how you can interact with a Google App Engine service.

Google Docs may be a simple place to store things on the web, but it may not be everything you need. I'll let you decide.